# How to get details of all the devices the user has logged in (active or persistent) - ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

Using ASP.NET Core 3.1 application. I am trying to get details (like name, IP address, and user-agent) of all the devices the user is now logged in (active and persistent logged-in devices). The requirement is similar to this page of our google account https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity
[image: Logged in devcies in asp.net core]

I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity, of course. Are there any standard practices to implement it? When I tried to search for this, I ended up getting the user details of the current session only. But I like to get all the remote logged-in device details of the user in asp.net core.

The hard-coded way is to maintain a table in DB for maintaining the logged-in and logged-out user details. But I hope there is a better way to do this. I welcome any recommendations or alternatives.

Comment: I think  maintaining a table in DB is better than getting all the devices once.Each time a user logged in,check his device and update the db.

Answer (score 2):

We faced a similar requirement. In addition to the information about all active sessions, we also needed a way to invalidate one or all sessions on the server side.

We have switched to persisting all sessions on the server in the DB. For this we wrote our own implementation of ITicketStore.

As a basis, here is a great article:
https://ml-software.ch/posts/implementing-a-custom-iticketstore-for-asp-net-core-identity